# What's wrong with these two sentences?

Tags: word-usage, as

My textbook says they are incorrect, but I fail to find their mistakes.

> Many men still have difficulty accepting a woman to be a business
>   partner.
>
> At the daycare center, the teachers treated the children like their
>   own children.

Comment: It would help if you added more detail. Which lesson in your book are these sentences from?

Comment: @ColleenV It's a examination unit. No contexts are provided.

Comment: What were you learning in the unit? Everything about English, or something more specific?

Comment: @ColleenV Everything about English, a general unit. It's not specific.

Answer (score 2):

I would reword like this:

Many men still have difficulty accepting a woman as their business partner.

At the daycare center, the teachers treated the children as if they were their own children. (I might omit the second "children.")

Comment: Thanks. I know both are unnatural but I have no idea if they are grammatically correct.

Comment: Do you mean only the first sentence is grammatically correct while the second one is incorrect?

Comment: "Many men still have difficulty accepting a woman to be a business partner."

It might not be grammatically correct because the verbs are in different tenses(?): "Men...accepting" and a "woman to be..."

Reword so the verbs are the same: Many men still have difficulty accepting a woman's being their business partner." But that makes "being" a gerund, so maybe not.

I don't know what's grammatically wrong with the other sentence. I can only see rewording it for clarification, like "At the daycare center, the teachers treated the children like they would their own children."

Comment: See http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/like-versus-as and https://www.grammarly.com/blog/like-vs-as/

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence is grammatically correct, but does not sound natural. Probably the only usages of the wording **accept *someone* to be** are in religious writing, for example:

> ...we pray that you, a non-Christian yet, accept Him to be your personal Savior and Lord... - *[The favor of God our trinity](https://books.google.co.id/books?id=zl-tBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA23&dq=%22accept%20him%20to%20be%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiKy-fflZXYAhUKqo8KHSDqDygQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=%22accept%20him%20to%20be%22&f=false)*

In this context, **accept *someone* to be** means starting something new- a transition- whereas in your sentence the intended meaning relates to something that will last for a while - a state. This can be better expressed using **as** or **in the role of**.

> Many men still have difficulty accepting a woman **as** a business partner.

The second sentence is also grammatically correct, but ambiguous because the intended meaning has been subjected to some clumsy [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis). The intended meaning is:

> At the daycare center, the teachers treated the children like they would treat their own children.

but it could be misinterpreted as

> At the daycare center, the teachers treated the children as if they were their own children.

The difference is one of emphasis: the intended meaning relates to the way the teachers behave toward the children, but the unintended meaning relates more to possesion/parentage.

Taking the intended meaning and applying a more natural ellipsis, **children** should go first, and then **treat** next. We have to retain **they would** in order to avoid ambiguity:

> At the daycare center, the teachers treated the children like they would treat their own.
>   At the daycare center, the teachers treated the children like they would their own.

Comment: Interesting, on the children in daycare question, I thought the idea you are labeling a "misinterpretation" was the intended meaning. I think both are very similar, though. I think the true potential for misinterpretation is  just the present indicative: _treated the children like they treat their own children_. After all, the teachers may or may not have their own children, at all. Still, +1.